# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' using ANN Visualizer

Tags: python, lstm

I used the package below to visualize the lstm architecture. However, I get the following error:

***CODE***

```
# Visualize the architecture

from ann_visualizer.visualize import ann_viz

ann_viz(lstm_model, view=True, title='LSTM Architecture')
```

***Output***

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-8cea540842d4> in <module>
      3 from ann_visualizer.visualize import ann_viz
      4 
----> 5 ann_viz(lstm_model, view=True, title='LSTM Architecture')

/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/ann_visualizer/visualize.py in ann_viz(model, view, filename, title)
     40     for layer in model.layers:
     41         if(layer == model.layers[0]):
---> 42             input_layer = int(str(layer.input_shape).split(",")[1][1:-1]);
     43             hidden_layers_nr += 1;
     44             if (type(layer) == keras.layers.core.Dense):

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Comment: Somehow `str(layer.input_shape).split(",")[1][1:-1]` was an empty string (`''`). Why that happened, we can't tell you without seeing the input you were trying to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `lstm_model` is a Keras Sequential model view ([ann_visualizer on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/ann_visualizer/))

It seems that this same problem was issued on [github](https://github.com/RedaOps/ann-visualizer/issues/7) as far back as 2018